# Issue in deleting raw from table sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite, tableview

this is what i am doing in header

```
static sqlite3 *database = nil;
static sqlite3_stmt *deleteStmt = nil;

@implementation SQLAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize navigationController;
@synthesize coffeeArray;
```

this is what i am using for deleting raw

```
    - (void) removeCoffee:(NSNumber *)coffeeObj {

      NSLog(@"coffeeObj%@",coffeeObj);

        int myInteger = [coffeeObj integerValue];
        NSLog(@"myInteger%d",myInteger);
      // print this myInteger0


        NSLog(@"%@",coffeeArray);
       //print object
   if (sqlite3_open([self getDBPath], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
   {    
   NSLog(@"myInteger%@",[self getDBPath]);

        NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"delete from Coffee where CoffeeID =%d",myInteger];

                             const char *del_stmt = [sql UTF8String];
       NSLog(@"%@",del_stmt); // getting print 
 // print this  delete from Coffee where CoffeeID =0.

                             sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, del_stmt, -1, & deleteStmt, NULL);
                 NSLog(@"sqlite3_step(deleteStmt) ==           SQLITE_DONE%@",sqlite3_step(deleteStmt) == SQLITE_DONE);

    // this print null

                             if (sqlite3_step(deleteStmt) == SQLITE_DONE)
                             { 
                               //NSLog(@"hi") this is not getting print

                             } else {
                                  //NSLog(@"hi") this is getting print
                             }
                             sqlite3_finalize(deleteStmt);
                             sqlite3_close(database);
    [coffeeArray removeObjectAtIndex:myInteger];
        NSLog(@"%@",coffeeArray);
       // object is deleted 
    }
}
```

my table is like below

```
table name = Coffee

CoffeeID(INTEGER)=0

CoffeeName(VARCHAR)=Latte

Price(REAL)=2.99
```

where thing runs perfectly object get deleted from array and thats why its not appearing on table cell. but its not getting deleted from database table thats why it when i launch app again then it shows again please help what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Put nslog in if and else condition where you compare SQLITE_DONE and check what it says !

Comment: its not going in if condition  jump from it sqlite3_finalize(deleteStmt);
sqlite3_close(database);

Comment: Check answer by @Ganapathy it should be connection issue only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before start deleting the object just conform once the database is opened properly or not. Just try like this.

```
//Setting path 
    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

      NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"database.db"]];

    const char *dbpath=[databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
      NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"delete from Coffee where CoffeeID =%d",myInteger];

                             const char *del_stmt = [sql UTF8String];

                             sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, del_stmt, -1, & deleteStmt, NULL);
                             if (sqlite3_step(deleteStmt) == SQLITE_DONE)
                             {

                             } else {

                             }
                             sqlite3_finalize(deleteStmt);
                             sqlite3_close(database);
    [coffeeArray removeObjectAtIndex:myInteger];
        NSLog(@"%@",coffeeArray);
       // object is deleted 

        }
```

Comment: Ganapathy i edited my question as per you said please check it again

Comment: So this if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK) statement is true as u said. Have u checked?

Comment: dbpath it should be only path or path/SQL.sqlite?

Comment: yes going in and as i have printed thing it gets print in that way

Comment: check once ur updated answer is right r not? i got some error.

Comment: everything is happening as i per i have nslog in my question

Comment: if (sqlite3_open([self getDBPath], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{

     NSLog(@"myInteger%@",[self getDBPath]);  
     // it prints this: myInteger/Users/CGTeam/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/21808AFD-354E-466D-9E96-261915E01483/Documents/SQL.sqlite

    - (void) removeCoffee:(NSNumber *)coffeeObj {  is it right ? its showing error on my side.

Comment: yes that is perectly right Ganapathy i did nslog for it its working

Comment: no i havent i just updated question so it become more easier for you to helo me check again

Comment: Can u please check and conform this code """ if (sqlite3_open([self getDBPath], &database) == SQLITE_OK)"" AND 

""    - (void) removeCoffee:(NSNumber *)coffeeObj { ""  are place in the right place(order wise) in ur code.. (see ur updated question)

Comment: sorry let me update question one more time. its not like that in my code

Comment: the question is updated as per you said. and in my real code it was like you said

Comment: Ganapathy dbpath should like //path/.sql.sqlite or it should be only path without fine name? in my code its with file name path/sql.sqlite

Comment: Ganapathy i found one thing and i think that is the problem  NSLog(@"sqlite3_step(deleteStmt) ==           SQLITE_DONE%@",sqlite3_step(deleteStmt) == SQLITE_DONE);
        
        // this print null

Comment: Just bring this statements "static sqlite3 *database and static sqlite3_stmt *deleteStmt" declaration inside the function "removeCoffee"(private scope) and check....

Comment: whats up? u fixed that issue?>

Comment: i am trying something else ones i will fix this stupid thing i will post it here Ganapathy. and i want to say thank you to you. for being here with me in this problem :) i will post answer here

Comment: Mostly the issue is only in connecting the table only i think so check the connections first.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(sqlite3_open([[self filepath] UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        Deletestatement = nil;  

        if(Deletestatement == nil)
        {
            const char *sql = "delete from Sqlitemanager2;";

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &Deletestatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }

        if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(Deletestatement)) //prathibha for problem in if
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

        sqlite3_finalize(Deletestatement);

    }
I hope this will help you.
```